# Not able to access wikitude architect package

Tags: java, android, wikitude, wikitude-sdk

I'm new to both android and wikitude. i'm trying to integrate wikitude with android. **I have downloaded trial version of wikitude sdk**.Trying to integrate it with indroid.

COnfigurations
I have put wikitude.aar in libs folder of my project.

Here is my build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wikidemo"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation(name: 'wikitude-native-sdk', ext: 'aar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.1.0'
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.wikidemo.MainActivity">

    <com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectView
        android:id="@+id/architectView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In settings.gradle

```
include ':app', ':plugins', ':wikitude-native-sdk'
```

Not able to access this package 
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: looks like you used the native SDK instead of the JS SDK library. (wikitude-native-sdk)

Comment: yup i have made that change and it works